# download from web

Tags: r

It's better not to use “for loop, while loop" in R, I want to downlod a url from web with two methods:

1.Using a for loop

```
url1="http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html"
url2="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz"
url=c(url1,url2)
dw=c("test1","test2")
for (i in 1:2){download.file(url[i],destfile=dw[i])}
```

How can I change "for loop" method into "apply" method?

2.Using RCurl

```
require(RCurl)
urls = c("http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz")
txt = getURIAsynchronous(urls)
```

How about the urls contain thousands of web address? If urls contain 10000 web addresses, There Is Not Enough Memory or Disk Space to ...

Comment: I agree, but think that I have decoded. The OP seems to want a vectorized version of download.file (in the first case). No idea about the RCurl enquiry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply`

```
urls <- rep('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169074/download-from-web',2) 
destfiles <- paste0('test',1:2,'.html')

mapply(download.file, url = urls, destfile = destfiles)
```

A similar approach should work for `RCurl`, although I cannot test this due to firewall / proxy restrictions

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your for loop question, you can use something like:

```
sapply(seq_along(url), function(n) download.file(url[n], dw[n])
```

which acts very similarly to your for loop.  Or @mnel has an excellent solution with `mapply`.  However, in this instance, using a for loop isn't frowned upon.  In fact, there are many ways of writing for loops that are not slow at all in R.  the R Inferno has a great section on this.

the shortest answer is that for loops in R are fine so long as the output is pre allocated rather than grown during the looping.

As far as your `RCurl` question, if you are getting a memory error, you have two choices.  1. get more memory. Or 2. download the data in chunks and write it to disk before downloading more.